Frequent, brief/intermittent halt of video after upgrade to 24.04 LTS
After upgrading to Kubuntu 24.04 LTS I am now experiencing frequent video "glitches" where the screen goes blank/dark for a second or so before it wakes up again. I see this when using a video monitor as an external screen with the laptop lid closed (the external monitor is the only display in use) connected via HDMI cable.
The only thing I've done so far to ameliorate this has been to update the Mesa video drivers from a third-party PPA:
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kisak/kisak-mesa -y
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version"
OpenGL version string: 4.6 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 24.2.3 - kisak-mesa PPA

Below are some system details:
KDE PLasma Version:     5.27.11
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.115.0
Qt Version:             5.15.13
Kernel Version:         6.8.0-44-generic (64-bit)
Graphics Platform:      X11
Graphics Processor:     Mesa Intel HS 520
Product:                Dell Latitude 7480

Other details:
journalctl -b | grep -i drm
Sep 17 11:28:58 jadams-dell-laptop-7480 kernel: ACPI: bus type drm_connector registered
Sep 17 11:28:58 jadams-dell-laptop-7480 kernel: [drm] Initialized simpledrm 1.0.0 20200625 for simple-framebuffer.0 on minor 0
Sep 17 11:28:58 jadams-dell-laptop-7480 kernel: simple-framebuffer simple-framebuffer.0: [drm] fb0: simpledrmdrmfb frame buffer device
Sep 17 11:28:58 jadams-dell-laptop-7480 systemd[1]: Starting modprobe@drm.service - Load Kernel Module drm...
Sep 17 11:28:58 jadams-dell-laptop-7480 systemd[1]: modprobe@drm.service: Deactivated successfully.
Sep 17 11:28:58 jadams-dell-laptop-7480 systemd[1]: Finished modprobe@drm.service - Load Kernel Module drm.
Sep 17 11:29:00 jadams-dell-laptop-7480 kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] VT-d active for gfx access
Sep 17 11:29:01 jadams-dell-laptop-7480 kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] Using Transparent Hugepages
Sep 17 11:29:01 jadams-dell-laptop-7480 kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] Disabling framebuffer compression (FBC) to prevent screen flicker with VT-d enabled
Sep 17 11:29:01 jadams-dell-laptop-7480 kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] Finished loading DMC firmware i915/skl_dmc_ver1_27.bin (v1.27)
Sep 17 11:29:01 jadams-dell-laptop-7480 kernel: [drm] Initialized i915 1.6.0 20230929 for 0000:00:02.0 on minor 1
Sep 17 11:29:01 jadams-dell-laptop-7480 kernel: fbcon: i915drmfb (fb0) is primary device
Sep 17 11:29:01 jadams-dell-laptop-7480 kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] fb0: i915drmfb frame buffer device
Sep 17 11:41:30 jadams-dell-laptop-7480 ksystemstats[2432]: Found unsupported GPU: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card1
Sep 17 12:27:01 jadams-dell-laptop-7480 kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* CPU pipe B FIFO underrun
Sep 17 14:27:37 jadams-dell-laptop-7480 kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* CPU pipe B FIFO underrun
Sep 17 19:18:37 jadams-dell-laptop-7480 kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* CPU pipe B FIFO underrun

Also
sudo dmesg | grep -i error
[168119.165099] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: AER: Correctable error message received from 0000:03:00.0
[168119.165135] pcieport 0000:03:00.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Correctable, type=Data Link Layer, (Receiver ID)
[168119.165149] pcieport 0000:03:00.0:   device [8086:15da] error status/mask=00000080/00002000
[171017.921032] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* CPU pipe B FIFO underrun
[171089.980853] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: AER: Correctable error message received from 0000:03:00.0
[171089.980862] pcieport 0000:03:00.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Correctable, type=Data Link Layer, (Receiver ID)
[171089.980865] pcieport 0000:03:00.0:   device [8086:15da] error status/mask=00000080/00002000
[171743.719785] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: AER: Correctable error message received from 0000:03:00.0
[171743.719831] pcieport 0000:03:00.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Correctable, type=Data Link Layer, (Receiver ID)
[171743.719851] pcieport 0000:03:00.0:   device [8086:15da] error status/mask=00000080/00002000
[174222.173714] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: AER: Correctable error message received from 0000:03:00.0
[174222.173769] pcieport 0000:03:00.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Correctable, type=Data Link Layer, (Receiver ID)
[174222.173788] pcieport 0000:03:00.0:   device [8086:15da] error status/mask=00000080/00002000
[178335.661092] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: AER: Correctable error message received from 0000:03:00.0
[178335.661137] pcieport 0000:03:00.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Correctable, type=Data Link Layer, (Receiver ID)
[178335.661151] pcieport 0000:03:00.0:   device [8086:15da] error status/mask=00000080/00002000
[180842.454504] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: AER: Correctable error message received from 0000:03:00.0
[180842.454518] pcieport 0000:03:00.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Correctable, type=Data Link Layer, (Receiver ID)
[180842.454540] pcieport 0000:03:00.0:   device [8086:15da] error status/mask=00000080/00002000
[181890.298590] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* CPU pipe B FIFO underrun
[182608.599510] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: AER: Correctable error message received from 0000:03:00.0
[182608.599533] pcieport 0000:03:00.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Correctable, type=Data Link Layer, (Receiver ID)
[182608.599541] pcieport 0000:03:00.0:   device [8086:15da] error status/mask=00000080/00002000
[182741.032957] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: AER: Correctable error message received from 0000:03:00.0
[182741.032981] pcieport 0000:03:00.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Correctable, type=Data Link Layer, (Receiver ID)
[182741.032989] pcieport 0000:03:00.0:   device [8086:15da] error status/mask=00000080/00002000
[185396.613388] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: AER: Correctable error message received from 0000:03:00.0
[185396.613401] pcieport 0000:03:00.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Correctable, type=Data Link Layer, (Receiver ID)
[185396.613405] pcieport 0000:03:00.0:   device [8086:15da] error status/mask=00000080/00002000
[185396.837733] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: AER: Correctable error message received from 0000:03:00.0
[185396.837790] pcieport 0000:03:00.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Correctable, type=Data Link Layer, (Receiver ID)
[185396.837815] pcieport 0000:03:00.0:   device [8086:15da] error status/mask=00000080/00002000
[186004.732216] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* CPU pipe B FIFO underrun
[187962.888045] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: AER: Correctable error message received from 0000:03:00.0
[187962.888058] pcieport 0000:03:00.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Correctable, type=Data Link Layer, (Receiver ID)
[187962.888062] pcieport 0000:03:00.0:   device [8086:15da] error status/mask=00000080/00002000
[187978.507099] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: AER: Correctable error message received from 0000:03:00.0
[187978.507125] pcieport 0000:03:00.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Correctable, type=Data Link Layer, (Receiver ID)
[187978.507136] pcieport 0000:03:00.0:   device [8086:15da] error status/mask=00000080/00002000
[187981.609957] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: AER: Correctable error message received from 0000:03:00.0
[187981.609969] pcieport 0000:03:00.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Correctable, type=Data Link Layer, (Receiver ID)
[187981.609973] pcieport 0000:03:00.0:   device [8086:15da] error status/mask=00000080/00002000
[188006.399109] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: AER: Correctable error message received from 0000:03:00.0
[188006.399124] pcieport 0000:03:00.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Correctable, type=Data Link Layer, (Receiver ID)
[188006.399144] pcieport 0000:03:00.0:   device [8086:15da] error status/mask=00000080/00002000
[188016.353144] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: AER: Correctable error message received from 0000:03:00.0
[188016.353153] pcieport 0000:03:00.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Correctable, type=Data Link Layer, (Receiver ID)
[188016.353156] pcieport 0000:03:00.0:   device [8086:15da] error status/mask=00000080/00002000
[188029.324550] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: AER: Correctable error message received from 0000:03:00.0
[188029.324566] pcieport 0000:03:00.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Correctable, type=Data Link Layer, (Receiver ID)
[188029.324571] pcieport 0000:03:00.0:   device [8086:15da] error status/mask=00000080/00002000
[188029.900876] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: AER: Correctable error message received from 0000:03:00.0
[188029.900892] pcieport 0000:03:00.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Correctable, type=Data Link Layer, (Receiver ID)
[188029.900898] pcieport 0000:03:00.0:   device [8086:15da] error status/mask=00000080/00002000

